# beautifulsoup - ignore unicode error and only print text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing a bit of web scraping, getting text from tables. Unicode errors keep popping up and when I encode to utf8 I get a bunch of `b'` and `b'\xc2\xa0'` mixed in with my results, is there a way to work around having to encode and only get texts from the tables?

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\...\...\...", line 15, in 
<module> print(rows) File 
"C:\...\...\...\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2612' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

When I use replace, I get a the type error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

regardless if I use `str()` or not. I have attempted to iterate through and print only items that can be converted into strings but again unicode error pops up

```
test = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019001392/msft-10q_20181231.htm'

import re

import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urlopen(test).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

tables = soup.findAll('table')

for table in tables:
  for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for cel in row.findAll('td'):
      if str(cel.getText().encode('utf-8').strip()) != "b'\\xc2\\xa0'":
        print(str(cel.getText().encode('utf-8').strip())
        #print(str(cel.getText().encode('utf-8').strip().replace('\\xc2\\xa0', '').replace('b\'', '')
```

Actual results:

```
b'\xe2\x98\x92'
b'QUARTERLY REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934'

b'\xe2\x98\x90'
b'TRANSITION REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934'

b'Washington'

b'\xc2\xa0'

b'91-1144442'

b'(State or other jurisdiction of\nincorporation or organization)'
...
...
```

Expected results:

```
'QUARTERLY REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934'

'TRANSITION REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934'

'Washington'

'91-1144442'

'(State or other jurisdiction of\nincorporation or organization)'

...
...
```

Comment: Don't encode!  Process text as text not byte strings.  Print text strings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen if i dont encode i get a 'charmap' codec can't encode character error

Comment: If I remove `encode()` then I get correct text on Linux. If you use Windows then maybe you have problem with console/terminal/cmd.exe which doesn't use UTF-8

Comment: Use Python 3.6+. That version and later use Unicode APIs to write directly to the terminal. Previous versions encode to the terminal encoding, which limits the code points that can be printed. If you can’t switch, use an IDE that supports UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup will already be correctly handling the HTML in utf-8 format, by encoding you are converting the string into bytes.

The following produced the required output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

test = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019001392/msft-10q_20181231.htm'
req = requests.get(test)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        for cel in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cel.get_text(strip=True)

            if text:   # skip blank lines
                print(text)
```

---

The HTML table could be stored as a list of lists as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

test = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019001392/msft-10q_20181231.htm'
req = requests.get(test)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

rows = []

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        values = [cel.get_text(strip=True) for cel in row.findAll('td')]
        rows.append(values)

print(rows)
```

Tested on:

Python 3.7.3, BS4 4.7.1
  Python 2.7.16, BS4 4.7.1

Comment: I'm using VS Code on Windows 10 and I am still getting: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\...\...", line 15, in <module>
    print(rows)
  File "C:\...\...\...\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2612' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: As the error relates to the `print(rows)` line, that issue is related to how your output console is configured in VS Code. The Python code itself is working fine. You'll need to configure VS Code to use `utf-8`.In Python 2.x, you can also configure it to emit `utf-8` output, see also `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`